# Gradle task vaadinBuildFrontend occasionally fails with pnpm issues, --parallel option is enabled

Tags: gradle, vaadin

I have a task execution of the Gradle task vaadinBuildFrontend and it occasionally fails with pnpm issues, most times it just succeeds fine.

The `--parallel` Gradle option is enabled.  Removing this option has not produced the problem.

Is the task designed to be executed in parallel (for a multi module build)?

```
> Task :web-locker:vaadinBuildFrontend FAILED
version check '/usr/bin/npx --yes --quiet pnpm' failed
com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendUtils$UnknownVersionException: Unable to detect version of pnpm. Using command /usr/bin/npx --yes --quiet pnpm --version
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendUtils.getVersion(FrontendUtils.java:1051)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendTools.validatePnpmVersion(FrontendTools.java:1104)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendTools.getSuitablePnpm(FrontendTools.java:1090)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunNpmInstall.createPnpmFile(TaskRunNpmInstall.java:529)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunNpmInstall.runNpmInstall(TaskRunNpmInstall.java:304)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunNpmInstall.execute(TaskRunNpmInstall.java:183)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeTasks.execute(NodeTasks.java:342)
    at com.vaadin.flow.plugin.base.BuildFrontendUtil.runNodeUpdater(BuildFrontendUtil.java:343)
    at com.vaadin.gradle.VaadinBuildFrontendTask.vaadinBuildFrontend(VaadinBuildFrontendTask.kt:71)

...

    at java.base@11.0.15/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendUtils$CommandExecutionException: Process execution failed with exit code 217
Output: 
Error output: npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     undefined,
npm WARN cleanup     TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined
npm WARN cleanup         at rm (node:internal/fs/promises:679:38)
npm WARN cleanup         at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:553:20
npm WARN cleanup         at Array.map (<anonymous>)
npm WARN cleanup         at [rollbackCreateSparseTree] (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:553:8)
npm WARN cleanup         at [reifyPackages] (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:256:31)
npm WARN cleanup         at async Arborist.reify (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:170:5)
npm WARN cleanup         at async exec (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/libnpmexec/lib/index.js:264:7)
npm WARN cleanup         at async module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:134:5) {
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rmdir
npm ERR! path /root/.npm/_npx/e6e0ed1aca658cae/node_modules/pnpm/dist/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp
npm ERR! errno -39
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/root/.npm/_npx/e6e0ed1aca658cae/node_modules/pnpm/dist/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-09-27T09_19_32_771Z-debug-0.log
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendUtils.executeCommand(FrontendUtils.java:1083)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendUtils.getVersion(FrontendUtils.java:1048)
    ... 136 more
```

Comment: Since you suspect parallel to be part of the problem, can we assume, that you have tried without it and the problem no longer persists?

Comment: I have switched to non-parallel but for final judgement I have to wait for a larger number of pipeline runs ...

Comment: Seems removing --parallel did the trick